# I need help navigating between 3 text inputs with a function

Tags: angular, typescript

I used 3 text inputs to create a custom input for phone numbers and am using `keyCode` in my function to make the cursor jump back and forth as the user types or deletes data.  [Here's a plunker to what I have.](https://plnkr.co/edit/2gHQwrqagGnbljo3bZmM)

This is my function so far

```
fieldJumper(event){
    let a = this.first;
    let b = this.second;
    let c = this.third;

    if(a.nativeElement.focus){
      if(this.NumA.length >2){
        if(event.keyCode !== 127 || event.keyCode !== 8 || event.keyCode !== 37){
          b.nativeElement.focus();
        }
      }
    }
    if(b.nativeElement.focus){
      if(this.NumB.length == 'null'){
        if(event.keyCode === 127 || event.keyCode === 8 || event.keyCode === 37){
          a.nativeElement.focus();
        }
      }
      else if(this.NumB.length > 2){
        if(event.keyCode !== 127 || event.keyCode !== 8 || event.keyCode !== 37){
          c.nativeElement.focus();
        }
      }
    }
    if(c.nativeElement.focus){
      if(this.NumC.length == 'null'){
        if(event.keyCode === 127 || event.keyCode === 8 || event.keyCode === 37){
          b.nativeElement.focus();
        }
      }
    }

 }
```

As you type it automatically jumps to the next field as desired, but doesn't jump back to previous field when deleting.  I've tinkered back and forth with the amount of `=` used.  I originally had `this.NumA.length < 1` rather than `this.NumA == 'null'`.

in the plunker you'll see this function as well

```
selection(){
    let a = this.first;
    let b = this.second;
    let c = this.third;

    if(this.NumA.length < 1 && this.NumB.length < 1 && this.NumC.length < 1 && !event.keyCode)

    { a.nativeElement.focus(); }

    if(this.NumA.length > 2 && this.NumB.length < 1 && this.NumC.length < 1 && !event.keyCode)

    { b.nativeElement.focus(); }

    if(this.NumA.length > 2 && this.NumB.length > 2 && this.NumC.length < 1 && !event.keyCode)

    {c.nativeElement.focus();}

}
```

This forces the proper text field to be selected based on the entry so far if any at all so users don't have to manually select fields with their pinky fingers.  I have it commented out because the functions collide with one another at the moment so I'm also trying to think of how to keep them from fighting one another.  Anybody know why the backspace doesn't trigger and how to keep these two functions from clashing?

**UPDATE**

switching to `(keydown)` in the template and fixing the `keycode` typos it now jumps from the 3rd to 2nd input when delete is pushed, but still doesn't jump to the first.

**UPDATE 02**

I got it to work by modifying my function to this

```
fieldJumper(event){
    let a = this.first;
    let b = this.second;
    let c = this.third;

    if(a.nativeElement.focus){
      if(this.NumA.length >2){
        if(event.keyCode !== 127 || event.keyCode !== 8 || event.keyCode !== 37){
          b.nativeElement.focus();
        }
      }
    }
    if(b.nativeElement.focus){
      if(this.NumB.length < 1 && this.NumA.length > 2){
        if(event.keyCode === 127 || event.keyCode === 8 || event.keyCode === 37){
          a.nativeElement.focus();
        }
      }
      else if(this.NumB.length > 2){
        if(event.keyCode !== 127 || event.keyCode !== 8 || event.keyCode !== 37){
          c.nativeElement.focus();
        }
      }
    }
    if(c.nativeElement.focus){
      if(this.NumC.length < 1 && this.NumB.length > 2){
        if(event.keyCode === 127 || event.keyCode === 8 || event.keyCode === 37){
          b.nativeElement.focus();
        }
      }
    }
 }
```

the difference is instead of just having

```
if(this.NumB.length < 1){...}

//and

if(this.NumC.length < 1){...}
```

I tried adding a condition for the state of the input it switches to like this

```
if(this.NumB.length < 1 && this.NumA.length > 2){...}

//and
if(this.NumC.length < 1 && this.NumB.length > 2){...}
```

it now goes back and forth from start to end.  Only problem now is I uncommented the other function and now it doesn't force the first input to be selected when you click within the empty field like it does without the `fieldJumper()` function.

**Update 03**

turns out my tablet added `.com` to a variable in the `selection()` function.  It works now, but it prevents the cursor from jumping backwards.

Comment: You write `keycode` instead of `keyCode` in some places. More important: you handle the `input` event with `fieldJumper`; I don't think that this event has the `keyCode` member.

Comment: good eye.  I just changed them and it didn't fix the problem.  also I originally had `(keydown)` instead of `(input)` because I came across another article that said it would be better to use `(input)` because of some keys that don't register with `keyup` or `keydown` and `input` was a safe way to retrieve all the keys.  So that's why I had it there.  I just changed back to `(keydown)` and am getting the same results.

Comment: @Optiq `(input)="fieldJumper($event)"` does not even generate an event with a `keyCode` at all. Did you try to `console.log(event)`?!  I see this: `{"isTrusted":true}`. **You should use `(keydown)`.**

Comment: I just came back to update my post.  I switched back to `(keydown)` and now it jumps back from the 3rd to the 2nd input, but still won't jump back into the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your event to keyup, for touch screens it may be keypress
and update you function

```
 fieldJumper(e){
    let cur = e.target.maxLength,
        val = e.target.value.length;
    if (cur == val) {
      if (e.target == this.first.nativeElement) this.second.nativeElement.focus();
      if (e.target == this.second.nativeElement) this.third.nativeElement.focus();
    }
    if (!val) {
      if (e.target == this.third.nativeElement) this.second.nativeElement.focus();
      if (e.target == this.second.nativeElement) this.first.nativeElement.focus();
    }
  }
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/DJGnbBMzgMEzfIDeZ32v?p=preview

The basic thing is that you should check the value state after the action is complete.

Event object always have "target" property, which contains element where event fired, you can use it instead of "if(a.nativeElement.focus)", - it's always true, because it's always not empty function.

And the last point that you may rely on your "maxLength" attribute and compare it with current value length.

As for "select" function problem, it's really quirky, the solution example is here
https://plnkr.co/edit/VOAU2nJjC44fBZ4M0CuF?p=preview

The point is to separate automatic focus from "fieldJumper" and from user input, to forbid change the input if lower one is not selected, so it may look like this:

```
private _autofocus = false;
selection(e){
    let a = this.first.nativeElement,
        b = this.second.nativeElement,
        c = this.third.nativeElement,
        cur = e.target;
    if (!this._autofocus && a.maxLength > a.value.length)
    return a.focus();

    if (!this._autofocus && b.value && (b.maxLength > b.value.length) 
    return b.focus();

    if (this._autofocus) this._autofocus = false;
  }

  fieldJumper(e){
    let cur = e.target.maxLength,
        val = e.target.value.length;

    if (cur == val) {
      if (e.target == this.first.nativeElement){
        this._autofocus = true;
        this.second.nativeElement.focus();
      }  
      if (e.target == this.second.nativeElement){
        this._autofocus = true;
        this.third.nativeElement.focus();
      }
    }
    if (!val) {
      if (e.target == this.third.nativeElement){
        this._autofocus = true;
        this.second.nativeElement.focus();
      }
      if (e.target == this.second.nativeElement){
        this._autofocus = true;
        this.first.nativeElement.focus();
      }
    }
  }
```

It's a bit straight forward, but I hope you'll be able to refine it.

Comment: I just tried your plunker and it doesn't jump backwards to the field before it.  Hopefully it's just a matter of you forgetting something simple because I would much rather use this way than the way I'm trying.

Comment: I've updated it several times (some variables were wrong), but checked just now, jumps back and forth, please reload and try once again

Comment: please disregard my edit to your post, I clicked the wrong one.

Comment: I tried it again and it didn't work at first but I changed the keyup to keydown and it went back and forth nice and smooth.  thanks.  Only thing is the `selection()` function stops it from working when I uncomment the if statements.  Is there a way to get those two to work together?

Comment: splendid.  I think I'm going to experiment with the input's `disabled` feature in the `selection()` function so I don't have to logic clashing with the same values being used inthe logic of the other function

Comment: that works perfectly THANKS!!!  the only thing I don't understand is how it works for you using `(keyup)`.  It won't work for me unless I switch it to `(keydown)`.

Comment: just to make sure I'm understanding correctly, saying `!this._autofocus` is the same as saying `_autofocus = false` right?

Comment: _autofocus == false, yes)